# Firestore Data not getting uploaded to Algolia

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am facing a problem of uploading `data(records)` from `firebase firestore` to `Algolia database`. I am using the `Algolia API` to upload data.

Here is the code of my index.js(code for uploading data from `firestore` into `Algolia`)-

```
// Import all needed modules.
const functions=require("firebase-functions");
const admin=require("firebase-admin");
const algoliasearch=require("algoliasearch");

// Set up Firestore.
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const env=functions.config();

// Set up Algolia.
const client = algoliasearch(env.algolia.appid, env.algolia.apikey);
const index = client.initIndex("users");

// Create a HTTP request cloud function.
async function sendCollectionToAlgolia() {

// This array will contain all records to be indexed in Algolia.
    var algoliaRecords = [];
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection('users').get();

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        const document = doc.data();

        const record = {
            objectID: doc.id,
            name: document.name,
            age: document.age,
            gender: document.gender,
            certificate: document.certificate,
            about: document.about,
            interestedIn: document.interestedIn,
            isVerified: document.isVerified,
            joinDate: document.joinDate,
            level: document.level,
            location: document.location,
            meetups: document.meetups,
            geoHash: document.geoHash,
            height: document.height,
            photoUrl: document.photoUrl,
            points: document.points,
            preferredBuddyFitnessLevel: document.preferredBuddyFitnessLevel,
            uid: document.uid,
            weight: document.weight,
            userFitnessLevel: document.userFitnessLevel
        };

        algoliaRecords.push(record);
    });

    // After all records are created, we save them to
    index.saveObjects(algoliaRecords,{ autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist: true })
        .then(objects =>{console.log(objects.firstname);})
        .catch(err=>{console.log(err);})
}
module.exports=sendCollectionToAlgolia;
```

Now after I execute `firebase deploy --only functions:sendCollectionToAlgolia` command in my terminal:
This is the output I get-[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THa24.png)

It is saying that the deployement is complete and successful but the data is not getting uploaded to my `Algolia Dashboard`

This is my `Algolia dashboard`-
[Algolia Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuuUK.jpg)

Here the data is not visible.

Help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see in the logs on running the function?

Comment: Are you asking about the `console.log` in this line of code- index.saveObjects(algoliaRecords,{ autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist: true })
        .then(objects =>{console.log(objects.firstname);})
        .catch(err=>{console.log(err);})
} If not can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about those `console.log` statements.

Comment: In the terminal it is showing me- `No log entries found`. I used this command in my terminal to view my logs-`firebase functions:log --only sendCollectionToAlgolia`